cannot activate a conda environment because conda init results in no action taken but must be run before conda activate
I am on ubuntu 24.04.01 lts and want to activate a conda environment and when I run
conda activate DL1-conda-env

I get CondaError: Run 'conda init' before 'conda activate'
However, running conda init gives:
no change     /home/david/anaconda3/condabin/conda no change     /home/david/anaconda3/bin/conda no change     /home/david/anaconda3/bin/conda-env no change     /home/david/anaconda3/bin/activate no change     /home/david/anaconda3/bin/deactivate no change     /home/david/anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh no change     /home/david/anaconda3/etc/fish/conf.d/conda.fish no change     /home/david/anaconda3/shell/condabin/Conda.psm1 no change     /home/david/anaconda3/shell/condabin/conda-hook.ps1 no change     /home/david/anaconda3/lib/python3.12/site-packages/xontrib/conda.xsh no change     /home/david/anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.csh no change     /home/david/.bashrc No action taken.

Also I had anaconda installed before and simply removed the anaconda3 directory with sudo rm -r anaconda3. Perhaps some old binaries cause the problem? I reinstalled anaconda3 by downloadin the ./Anaconda3-2024.10-1-Linux-x86_64.sh  file and executing it.
(I didnt figure out how to put the output on multiple lines maybe someone knows how to?
Edit: I found this but now I get a command not found "conda" error when running conda init.
conda init gives me "no action taken"
